# Need to export data as CSV from DB which holds million of records. Also need to overwrite the row in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I have million of records and i need to export that data to csv. I did that using PG copy data and retrieved data and wrote it to CSV.

One modification needed in the flow is modify the data retrieved from get_copy_data and then write back to csv

do you guys know any optimized way to achieve that ?

```
sql_query = 'SELECT encrytped_data_field1, encrytped_data_field2 from table'
    destination = "data.csv"
    no_of_rows = 0
    File.open(destination, "w") do |file|
      file.puts '"Decryted data field 1","Decryted data field 2"'
      conn = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.raw_connection
      conn.copy_data "COPY (#{sql_query}) TO STDOUT WITH CSV;" do
        while row = conn.get_copy_data
          #row holds the value of encrypted data field 1 and 2 . Need better way to call helper method and decrpty back  
          file.write(row)
          no_of_rows +=1
        end
      end
    end 
    return no_of_rows
```

Comment: On what OS? a shell script might prove a better option

Comment: this is controller method written in Ruby on Rails. Data needs to be modified before writing to CSV. need suggestion which is better in terms of memory n time usage

Comment: How do you need to modify the data? It might be much faster to modify it in a shell script on the fly instead of in Ruby. On the other hand if you want to do this in Ruby why don't you use Rails finder methods?

Comment: i need to decrypt the data using helper method ( uses ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor ) and return back the CSV data from the Rails controller .

Comment: You could write a rake tassk and call it from a shell script. You have been asked twice now what OS but you haven't answered that question. There are many ways to achieve this and you are asking for the most efficient

Comment: sorry about the skipping the OS. It is Linux. also i tried another way 

Called copy_data with decoder - https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/pg/PG%2FConnection:copy_data (gives array) 

while row = conn.get_copy_data
            csv << row.map!{ |r| r.is_a?(String) ? crypt.decrypt_and_verify(r) : r }
            no_of_rows +=1
 end

this works but need thoughts on performance aspect

Answer (score 1):

For such a large file in a web request, you'll want to implement streaming downloads. Otherwise, you'd have to either hold a ton of raw data in memory (bad) or write a ton of data to disk just to delete it moments later (also bad).

You should be able to find examples easily, e.g. https://www.bernardo.me/blog/2017/06/28/streaming-csv-with-rails/ and https://medium.com/table-xi/stream-csv-files-in-rails-because-you-can-46c212159ab7

You'll see that you will have access to bits of the file as it streams, so you'll have to make your modifications while streaming too.